# How to reboot LDAP service in win2k?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to view a user in LDAP which was recently added to a Windows 2000 Active Directory Service.  I'm not seeing the user when I query LDAP, and I'm guessing I need to reboot the service.  Any advice for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that you cannot reboot the LDAP service in win2k.  So I rebooted the entire machine, and it works fine now.

If somebody can post how to reboot just the LDAP service, I'd be more than happy to mark that answer correct.

Comment: Win2000/2003 doesn't support "LDAP" service restart, you would have to restart the server itself. 

But in Windows 2008 it comes as a service.

Comment: That is all I needed to know!  If you want the free rep, post that as an answer and I'll check it.  I don't like answering my own question.

Answer (score 4):

No no no no no no no.  And might I add, no.

It's a common misconception that the solution to all Windows problems is a reboot or a restart of something.  Sometimes it does fix it, but what have you learned about what caused the problem, and what have you learned about how to fix it properly or how to avoid it in future?

Like **Kevin** said, first of all give us some more info about your environment.  Secondly, let us know what you mean by "when I query LDAP".  Are you using some third party tool for this, or submitting an LDAP query in code?  There may be something amiss in your LDAP query, and trying to brute-force a fix by just rebooting the server or restarting the LDAP service will never fix it if so.  Can you see the user in AD Users & Computers?  Can you bind to the DN of the user?

Comment: As I responded to Kevin, this is a single-server environment, just a small network.  I am connecting to the LDAP server using a Cisco tool, and listing all of the users on the LDAP server.  I can see all except the one that I added yesterday.

Comment: First thing you need to check is whether or not any other LDAP client can connect to it.  I'd use something like Softerra LDAP browser for this.  This step will establish if the problem is at the AD side or the Cisco side.

Answer (score 1):

Is your environment a multiple domain controller configuration?  If so, the change was probably made connected to a different domain controller and you need to wait for it to replicate between them, force replication, or simply connect your LDAP client to the same domain controller the user was added on.

Comment: Single server environment, so not a replication issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to see other users in the AD, I'd say it's either because security/permissions related issue with the account you bind to LDAP (you do define user account and not using anonymous binding?) or possibly limitation in Cisco's tool (maybe not showing up all accounts that query returns?).

Can you verify if another newly created account shows up?